# Convert all product prices current excluding tax to including tax

Tags: magento2, product, price, tax, tax-calculation

I want to convert all prices of my products from excluding tax to including tax.
I have a german Magento 2.1.8 shop, so I would need to multiply by/include 19 % tax:
`net price * 1,19 percent german tax = price including tax`

Doing this manually is not possible (I currently have 13000 products created).
Which tables in the database do I need to modify? I have only configurable and simple products.

Answer (score 1):

to modify a Magento attribute on a store basis, you may use the function **updateAttributes**. Please see below a snippet that may show you how it could work:

```
<?php
      $storeId = 'germanStoreId';

      $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
      $collection->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite();

      foreach ($collection as $product) {

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
            array($productId),
            array('price' => $product->getPrice()*1.9),
            $storeId
        );

     }
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you know which tables in the database I need to modify to convert all net prices to prices including tax?

Answer (score 1):

**Make a backup first! And test first in develop environment.**

To convert all prices from net (german: netto) to gross (german: brutto) ones, you need to issue the following SQL statement.

But at first you need to obtain your attribute_id of the `price` attribute. To do so, go to backend > stores > attributes > product and click on the `price` attribute.
Obtain the id from the URL (see screenshot below):

[image: find out attribute id of price]

In this case it is `67` but yours can be different!

`Update catalog_product_entity_decimal set value = ROUND(value*1.19, 2) WHERE attribute_id = #your_attribute_id#`

where `#your_attribute_id#`would be your previously obtained attribute_id of the `price` attribute (in this case `67`).

**This query will also round your prices!** F.e. if your net price was `19.3193` the result will be `22.99`.

If you have **special prices** on some of your products, you do need to repeat the above steps for the attribute_id corresponding to the attribute `special_price`.

Do not forget to set your catalog prices to `including tax`. Afterwards reindex prices via cli `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.